# searching a pattern with cppcheck (pcre) regular expression

Tags: regex, cppcheck

I have a code snippet int t.c like

```
val =  (val1 << 8) | (val >> 8 );
val =  (val2 << 16) | (val >> 8 );
val =  (val3 << 32) | (val >> 8 );
val =  (val << 8);
```

I will get ouput if I grep as  `grep -nhE "(<<.*|).*(>>)" t.c`

```
1:val =  (val1 << 8) | (val >> 8 );
2:val =  (val2 << 16) | (val >> 8 );
3:val =  (val3 << 32) | (val >> 8 );
```

But If search with cppcheck like  `./cppcheck --rule="(<<.*|).*(>>)" t.c` I will get output

```
[../test/t.c:1]: (style) found ' val = ( val1 << 8 ) | ( val >> 8 ) ; val = ( val2 << 16 ) | ( val >> 8 ) ; val = ( val3 << 32 ) | ( val >>'
```

ie the whole matching lines together from first matching is displaying. I want the result as in grep command.

Please help

Comment: your rule is overly complicated. due to the alternation operator `|` you are effective searching for `>>`only.
combining the simpler expression with vs-compatible output, use `./cppcheck --template=vs --rule=">>" t.c`. you may define your own template for formatting the output, see [chapter 5 of the manual](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following command (escaped `|`):

```
cppcheck --rule="<<.*?\|.*?>>" t.c
```

*The output is not exactly same as that of grep.*